# 500 Error when setting up Swagger in asp .net CORE / MVC 6 app

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swashbuckle

I'm trying to setup a basic swagger API doc in a new asp .net CORE / MVC 6 project and receiving a 500 error from the swagger UI:
`500 : http://localhost:4405/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

My startup class has the following code in it:

```cs
using Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen;
using Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen.XmlComments;
using Swashbuckle.Application;
....
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...
  services.AddSwaggerGen();
  services.ConfigureSwaggerDocument(options =>
  {
    options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Blog Test Api",
        Description = "A test API for this blogpost"
    });
  });
}
```

and then under Configure:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
....
  app.UseSwaggerGen();
  app.UseSwaggerUi();
....
}
```

When i build and run the project, the UI will come up when i go to swagger/UI/index.html, but the 500 error above is displayed. When i go to the swagger/v1/swagger.json link, console gives the following 500 error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Is there any way i can figure out the root cause of the 500 or enable any additional debug in swagger to figure out why it's throwing this error? Based on some of the tutorials i've looked at, only what i have in startup is required for a base implementation. Please let me know if i can provide any additional information.

EDIT: this is for rc1, and may not be relevant to the new netcore 1.0 currently out (6/29/2016)

Comment: I get notifications about this question from time to time and it warms my heart to see how far swashbuckle has come with .net web api's now. From it's infancy in pre-release .net core to now a standard inclusion in .net 6.

Comment: This is still helpful in 2023 with .NET 7. Preventing lots of headaches

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Initially I got a 500 error too. Deep down in the stacktrace it said:
System.NotSupportedException: Unbounded HTTP verbs for path 'api/hotels'. Are you missing an HttpMethodAttribute?

It turned out I was missing a HttpGet attribute for one of my api methods:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
```

also if you used a method with a parameter like this "Get(int id)"
you will get the same error without an explanation so you need to add it into the decoration
"[HttpGet("{id:int}")]"

Comment: Where do you get the stack trace? I just get the 500 error in my web client without further information. The server does not throw an exception.

Comment: The error message and stacktrace occured when opening the API's Swagger documentation site, i.e. https://myapi.somedomain.com/help/index

Comment: if method should not be added to swagger, you can make it protected

Comment: Swagger really should handle this with a custom error.

Comment: One more , it turned  one of the POST action method has invalid parameters

Comment: Thanks, it really worked for me after 2 hours of research. In my case, I missed out  [HttpGet] Attribute on the Controller Action Method level.

Comment: In my case was because I created two methods with same route by mistake

Comment: In my case, I had given a duplicate Route

Comment: Damn why swagger is still so raw and unpolished, this is very basic stuff :C

Comment: You saved me. In my case, I was duplicating the [HTTPGet] attribute at a controller.

Comment: I added a private method to my controller but declared it public by mistake. A slightly different flavor of: public-method + no-http-attribute = .net-swagger-bombs

Comment: Can't believe, swagger crashes if one out of thousand methods is not according to it's expectations?

Answer (score 306):

If someone want to know the exact error is in the Swagger's stack trace, request the URL:

```
<your-app-url>/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

Or, click on the `swagger.json` link from the browser dev tools console:

[image: Chrome DevTools with error log]

Which will show the error in your IDE Output:

[image]

Comment: That's the perfect way to find out what is really the problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. There's loads of posts about this on the net, generally with guesses as to what the problem is rather than suggestions on how to debug. This method of debugging is actually all I wanted to know.

Comment: Not working for me. Clicking on link or going to address gave me error 500.

Comment: @ohdev Check the order of the middleware pipeline. If UseSwagger comes before any kind of exception handling/logging, that could cause any errors to not be logged

Comment: @Sangman Thanks. I got solution at another comment and I just simply had to change method access qualifier from my controller from public to protected. That's all.
Swagger is expecting request type attribute (HttpPost, HttpGet and so on) for every public method in controller.

Comment: Another quick way is to goto chrome debugger-> network tab-> preview. You will get the stack trace for the error.

Comment: Thanks god I didn't jump out of window before seeing your answer

Comment: Using dotnet 6 in 2022, and this is still relevant. Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me, but I also turned on all exceptions and disabled 'just my code' in the Visual Studio debugging options and the exeption popped up.

Comment: thanks @Zin Min.  Not of the anther answered really helped.  In my case, I had 2 mondels that had the same name.  I would have never figured that out

Answer (score 27):

I got this error when one of my functions was marked as `public`, but wasn't meant to be a web service which could be called directly.

Changing the function to `private` made the error go away.

Alternatively, immediately before your `public` function, you can put the `[NonAction]` command, to tell Swagger to ignore it.

```
[NonAction]
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeEvent(string id)
{ 
   ...
}
```

(I wish Swagger would actually report the *name* of the function which caused this problem though, rather than just complaining that it could no longer find the "*../swagger/v1/swagger.json*" file... that's not particularly useful.)

Comment: In my case, public method from my BaseController should have change from public to protected. But your method was inspiration for me.

Comment: It took me so long to find this solution

Comment: In my case I was inheriting a BaseController which had some methods without this attribute. Adding this attribute solved my problem.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly you can enable the developer exception page by adding `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` on your Configure() in order to see better which is the root cause. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)

In my case the problem was that I have to install also `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` nuget in order to make Swagger work.

Try also to uninstall/reinstall `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` nuget.

Comment: This fixed it for me

Comment: uninstall/reinstall Swashbuckle.AspNetCore doesnt work for me

Comment: I had followed the directions from http://www.talkingdotnet.com/add-swagger-to-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api/ but for an API that I was upgrading from Core 1.1.  Adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles worked from me.

Comment: Cause for the error can be different in different cases. So, it is must to understand the root cause of the issue. fix might be simpler like in my case. Adding app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); in Configure() of start up helped me identify root cause and the fix was really simple

Comment: `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` doesn't make any difference for me. I keep getting the same useless page

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem today and the cause was that some methods on my controllers API was missing [HttpGet]:

[image]

The exception (in stack trace) showed me the problme
You can also check the exception in the Output window in Visual Studio like this (in my case it showed me):

[image]

Comment: This was the answer that helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In my case I was missing an action in route attribute which exist in your API controller.

Something like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Before I had:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

An error occoures when writing **[Route("api/[controller]")]** because swagger doesn't know how to separate the API methods without action inside your route attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this took 30 min of googling to find the right answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Look here if you're not able to load the and look at the swagger.json in the console.

Swagger has a difficult time negotiating the differences between namespaces.  When building the objects expected for api calls it will index through each defined class.  If there are two classes that share a class name it won't be able to process the swagger.json file.

Example of two classes that .Net will process correctly, but Swagger will not.

```
namespace MyCompany.PaymentProcessor.DTO
{

    public class Payment
    {
      //dto content
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace MyCompany.CbData
{

    public class Payment
    {
       //couch base data
    }
}
```

Will be treated correctly by .Net, but unresolvable by swagger.

Comment: That was a great find!

Comment: Thanks for this one, took me 40min to find the error. Because there is no exception in the output.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add **[HttpGet]** or [HttpPost] on top of api actions.
2. Add **[Reout("YourApiActionName")]** on top of api actions ,

   or add **[Route("[controller]/[action]")]** on top of your Controller class.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and the error message helped me identify the root cause:

```
{
  "error": "Conflicting method/path combination \"POST api/calls\" for actions - SMSApi_v2.Controllers.CallController.CreateCall (SMSApi_v2),SMSApi_v2.Controllers.CallController.CreateCalls (SMSApi_v2). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround"
}
```

The root were these lines of code:

```
    **[HttpPost("calls")]**
    public IActionResult CreateCall([FromBody]Call call)
    {
        repository.Create(call);
        return Ok(call);
    }

    **[HttpPost("calls")]**
    public IActionResult CreateCalls([FromBody] string xmlFile)
    {
        var calls = xmlProcessor.DeserializeTo<List<Call>>(xmlFile);
        if (!calls.Any())
            return BadRequest("Deserializing was not done correctly.");

        repository.Create(calls);
        return Ok(calls);
    }
```

Even if the signatures of the methods are different, the two API verbs have the same route and this is generating the error.

Answer (score 2):

Might you've missed adding API verb to an endpoint. Can use below header as your need

```
1.[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
2.[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost]
```

Answer (score 2):

This came because you have a no-action method on your controller class check that missed an HTTP attribute on any of the controller action methods.  If you need a no-action or no need for access from external methods declaration then make it private, you will fix this issue.

private void MyMethod()
{

}

Comment: This one was my case thanks

Answer (score 1):

Also if I may add, the swagger set up does not like it when you route at the root level of your controllers. For example:

Do not do this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("/v1/myController")]
[Authorize]
public class myController
{
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(RestOkResponse<Response>))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(RestErrorResponse))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(RestErrorResponse))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, Type = typeof(RestErrorResponse))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] MyObject myObject)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize]
public class myController
{
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(RestOkResponse<Response>))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Type = typeof(RestErrorResponse))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(RestErrorResponse))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, Type = typeof(RestErrorResponse))]
    [SwaggerResponse((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
    [HttpPost("/v1/myController")]
    [Authorize()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] MyObject myObject)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

It took me a while to figure that the reason why I was getting internal server error was because of this routing issue. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Might be obvious but, besides missing the `HttpGet` or `HttpPost` attributes, don't forget to differentiate the post methods.

You may have 2 different methods (with different names) marked with `HttpPost`, and that would also cause this kind of issue. Remember to specify the method name in the attribute: `[HttpPost("update")]`.

Answer (score 1):

in some cases, the **router of controller** is duplicated. Review the last **controller** modified.

Comment: You need review and check router's controllers...after this, build and run again. This is only a suggestion. In my case, this solved my problem...

Answer (score 1):

I get same error in ASP.NET Boilerplate. I searched a lot and found a problem with my code. I use same name two DTO object, but located different namespaces.

For example first DTO object is like as below:

```
namespaces Test{
    public class TestDto
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
    }
}
```

And second DTO object is like as below:

```
namespaces Test_2{
    public class TestDto
    {
        public int Id{get;set;}
    }
}
```

I changed Test_2.TestDto's name, problem did solve for me after.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a model has the same name as another model, I fixed changing the name

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at this project.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/tree/master/test/WebSites/Basic

This repo is from Swashbuckle´s owner, is a basic ASP.NET 5 Sample app, this is help you to correct configure yours middlewares (and take care about the orders of them, it´s matter, e.g., use "app.UseSwaggerGen();app.UseSwaggerUi(); after app.UseMvc();)

To enable logging in your applcation give a look at:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html?highlight=logging
(the log will be generated inside "wwwroot" folder

Comment: I tried to get this working with the project i really wanted to add swashbuckle to but it just won't work. I think there may be something in the controller routes that's causing it to get hung up. Following the above i was able to add it to a new .net project with no issues. The issue i'm running into is definitely project specific. Will mark as accepted answer and if i can ever figure out which specific routes are causing the issue i will update the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When I Add the parameter Version , it works

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem. In my case, it was caused by two endpoints in the same controller with the same route and method name (but different parameter types). Of course, it then became apparent that that was probably poor practice anyway so I changed the endpoint names and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because in STARTUP.CS I not put the version's name in SwaggerDoc parameters:

Error => `c.SwaggerDoc("", blablabla`

WORK => `c.SwaggerDoc("v1",blablabla`

then, now are ok fine!

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => 
    {
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info {Title = "PME SERVICES", Version = "v1"});
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today configuring Swagger in a .Net Core 2.2 Web Api project. I started down the path that @Popa Andrei mentions above by including the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` dependency in my project as I figured that was most likely the culprit. That turned into a rabbit hole of chaining dependencies although it did ultimately work for me.

I then realized that in my `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` I had `services.AddMvcCore(...)` which just gives you bare bones and you add dependencies as you need them. When I changed that to `services.AddMvc(...)` it started working without having to manually add all the dependencies required by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`.

That doesn't mean you can't take the route of staying with `services.AddMvcCore(...)` and then adding all the necessary dependencies. You can, and it will work.

It is just much easier to take the `services.AddMvc(...)` approach and be done.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure my swagger versions lined up with each other fixed my issue. Since I was starting a new project I set my api version to be v0.1

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v0.1", new Info { Title = "Tinroll API", Version = "v0.1" });
});
```

But had left my swagger url to be v1.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Tinroll API v0.1");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

I updated my versioning to be `/swagger/v0.1/swagger.json` instead of `v1` and Swagger worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see the solution which worked for me posted here, I will contribute one to the ongoing thread. In my case, it was the Route attribute was set separately with the HttpPost/HttpGet at the function level (not controller level).

**INCORRECT:**

```
[HttpPost]

[Route("RequestItem/{itemId}")]
```

**CORRECT:**

```
[HttpPost("RequestItem/{itemId}")]
```

Also, the Swagger seems to expect Ok(object) result instead of StatusCode(object) result for a success request to return.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of having two class types with the same name but with different namespaces, which are used as the return type of two different actions in different controllers!

When I changed the name of one of them, the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was due to OData. If I just commented out my services.AddOData(); I didn't get any error.[just comment out the services.AddOData();](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PesId.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Swagger, which is enabled by default in .Net Core 5, it needs to know something about your methods. Normally, you don't need to add `[HttpGet]` attribute because it is the default `HttpMethod` for your methods, but swagger requires that information to generate documentation of your code.

So adding `[HttpGet]` above my method solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error 500: http://localhost:4405/swagger/v1/swagger.json
```

This error can occur when there are multiple endpoints, for example, two endpoints in the same controller with the [HttpPost] annotation. When this happens, it is necessary to differentiate them, using for example [HttpPost] on one and [HttpPost("User")] on the other.

Answer (score 0):

For swagger your API controller's all public method should be marked with [HttpGet/HttpPost/HttpPut/HttpDelete] or [NonAction] attribute.

If your controller is inheriting from ApiController, make sure your swagger is not complaining on **ExecuteAsync** method.

[image]

In this case you just need to override ExecuteAsync method in your controller and add [NonAction] attribute on it.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The setup for Swagger is varying greatly from version to version. This answer is for Swashbuckle 6.0.0-beta9 and Asp.Net Core 1.0. Inside of the ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs, you need to add -

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
      c.SingleApiVersion(new Info
      {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "My Awesome Api",
        Description = "A sample API for prototyping.",
        TermsOfService = "Some terms ..."
      });
    });
```

Then in the Configure method you must add -

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwaggerGen();
    app.UseSwaggerUi();
}
```

Be sure you are referencing in Startup.cs -

using Swashbuckle.SwaggerGen.Generator;

My project.json file looks like -

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Swashbuckle": "6.0.0-beta9"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "xmlDoc": false
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To see the source of exception

- open chrome browser
- open developer tools
- see exceptions in console tab
- fix it.

Comment: It would be better if you give a proper explanation instead of asking us to go to console !

Comment: You're right. I tried to explain that there is no specific solution about it. The source of problem might be in console message.