# Grouping Swagger by Project in .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am working on a project which I named as "main-project". I have at least 10 different small project in there and this project will probably grow. I have just one swagger for all these projects because all these projects use just one dotnet core web application for generalization purpose.

For example, let's say I have project named `SchoolJob` and project named `HospitalJob`. `SchoolJob` has three different endpoints named `GetStudents`, `TakeStudents`, `GetPayment` and `HostpitalJob` has two endpoint named `GetDoctors` and `GetNurses`. These two different project will be seen in one swagger UI like that:

```
 - ../schooljob/getstudents
 - ../schooljob/takestudents 
 - ../schooljob/getpayment
 - ../hospitaljob/getdoctors
 - ../hospitaljob/getnurses
```

What I want to do is setting multiple different swagger page in one dotnet core web project or grouping one swagger so that they will be seen on different page / or on the same page but not the same time.

../mainproject/swagger1/index.html or mainproject/swagger/schooljob UI should be like that:

```
 - ../schooljob/getstudents
 - ../schooljob/takestudents 
 - ../schooljob/getpayment
```

../mainproject/swagger2/index.html or mainproject/swagger/hospitaljob UI should be like that

```
 - ../hospitaljob/getdoctors
 - ../hospitaljob/getnurses
```

```cs
// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("schooljob", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "schooljob",
        Title = "School Job"
    });
    c.SwaggerDoc("hospitaljob", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "hospitaljob",
        Title = "Hospital Job"
    });
    // c.AddSecurityDefinition... and other swagger configurations
}   
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "mainproject/swagger/{documentname}/swagger.json";
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mainproject/swagger/schooljob/swagger.json", "School Job");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mainproject/swagger/hospitaljob/swagger.json", "Hospital Job");
        c.RoutePrefix = "mainproject/swagger";
        /c second prefix how?
    });
}
```

```cs
// SchoolController.cs

[HttpPost("schooljob/getstudents")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "schooljob")]
public JsonResult GetStudents([FromBody]OnaySayfasiId onaySayfasi)
{ ... }
```

```cs
// HospitalController.cs

[HttpPost("hospitaljob/getdoctors")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "hospitaljob")]
public JsonResult GetDoctors([FromBody]OnaySayfasiId onaySayfasi)
{ ... }
```

By the way, I tried using grouping by Api Version but I saw all these endpoints again. Is there any method for doing this?

Comment: I think using the API versioning should do the job, what did you try exactly?

Comment: Also did you try to call `app.UseSwaggerUI(options => { options.RoutePrefix = "swaggerXX" ...  })` multiple times in `Startup.cs`? Each call creating a different Swagger page?

Comment: How should I do it? Like `mainproject/swagger/schooljob` and `mainproject/swagger/hospitaljob`? Tried it with multiple multiple `SwaggerEndpoint` but it didn't work.

Comment: There is just "Select a definition" list on the top-right of the UI and I can select versions. But these two versions have the same endpoint. I have `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "projectName")]` in only two endpoints and other endpoints don't have this.

Comment: Could you add more code to your question, `Startup.cs` and some of yours controllers? It would help a lot to help debug

Comment: I couldn't reach the code at weekend, so here my example code.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're missing, you used the wrong controller attribute, here what you can do:

- In the controllers, you have to use `[ApiVersion]` instead of the `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = ...)]` attribute. Groups are different, I guess they are about grouping endpoints under the same section in the Swagger page.
- When a method argument requires a version, be consistent. `OpenApiInfo`, `SwaggerEndpoint`, `ApiVersion` need the same string, for example `schooljob` and not `School Job`.

I guess it should work if you update your code as below:

```cs
// Startup.cs

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mainproject/swagger/schooljob/swagger.json", "schooljob");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/mainproject/swagger/hospitaljob/swagger.json", "hospitaljob");
        c.RoutePrefix = "mainproject/swagger";
        // No need for 2nd route prefix as there is only one Swagger page,
        // the content of the page gets updated when selecting a different version in the combobox.
    });

/* This line may be required in ConfigureServices method, give it a try */
/* services.AddApiVersioning(); */
```

```cs
// SchoolController.cs

[HttpPost("schooljob/getstudents")]
[ApiVersion("schooljob")]
public JsonResult GetStudents([FromBody]OnaySayfasiId onaySayfasi)
{ ... }
```

I hope it solves your problem!

Comment: When I used `ApiVersion` I got 'Fetch errorInternal Server Error /bilgemuygulamalari/swagger/toplantiodasi/swagger.json'. What could be the problem?

Comment: You can debug it as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788911/500-error-when-setting-up-swagger-in-asp-net-core-mvc-6-app)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't debug errors on Output, browser console or browser network. For example response of `/mainproject/swagger/hospitaljob/swagger.json` returns empty.

Comment: I am trying to debug swagger but there is no error message on Chrome, Visual Studio or Postman or any other browser etc. My json is always empty

Comment: Oh I forgot something, the thing is your API doesn't know where to pick the version. You must use a `{version:apiVersion}` in your routes for that. For example, try `[HttpPost("{version:apiVersion}/getstudents")]` on top of your method, or try `[Route("{version:apiVersion}")]` on top of your controller.

Comment: Should I use `[ApiVersion("schooljob")]`? I tried using both` [HttpPost("{version:apiVersion}/getstudents")]` and `[Route("{version:apiVersion}")]` and nothing displayed. Also, I tried changing `version:apiVersion` as `version:schooljob` but swagger didn't run at all. Btw, in .net Core 3.1, i had to use `services.AddVersionedApiExplorer();` after `services.AddApiVersioning();`. The 500 error was gone, but nothing was displayed.

Comment: Yes you should use `[ApiVersion("schooljob")]` and `[Route("{version:apiVersion}")]` on top of your controller, and `[HttpPost("getstudents")]` on top of your method. `[ApiVersion]` tells the API that this controller is only for the version `schooljob`. `[Route]` tells the API how to extract the version from the route.

Comment: At long last, I could run my application. Your suggestion helped a lot but several things were of. I needed to add my controller class `[ApiController]` attribute. I had to add `services.AddVersionedApiExplorer();` to my `startup` - `ConfigureServices`. I didn't need  `{version:apiVersion}` but i used it anyway. And lastly, for the versioning I should have used `"1.0"` or `"2.0"` instead `"schooljob"` because there was a rule for versioning in .net core 3.1. Now, I will try to override this rule.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Well, I think your last call would be to create 2 json files and serves 2 distinct Swagger pages for this. Calling `app.UseSwaggerUI()` (with a different `options.RoutePrefix`) is enough for two distinct pages. The hard stuff is more about the 2 json files I think

Answer (score 0):

use the below code in program.cs (.net 6), If you are using .net 5(or below version) use this code in strartup.cs

```
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });


services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {

            options.DocInclusionPredicate((documentName, apiDescription) =>
            {
                var actionApiVersionModel = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetApiVersionModel();
                var apiExplorerSettingsAttribute = (ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute)apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.First(x => x.GetType().Equals(typeof(ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute)));
                if (actionApiVersionModel == null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                if (actionApiVersionModel.DeclaredApiVersions.Any())
                {
                    return actionApiVersionModel.DeclaredApiVersions.Any(v =>
                    $"{apiExplorerSettingsAttribute.GroupName}v{v}" == documentName);
                }
                return actionApiVersionModel.ImplementedApiVersions.Any(v =>
                       $"{apiExplorerSettingsAttribute.GroupName}v{v}" == documentName);
            });

            var apiVersionDescriptionProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();
            foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc($"Orders{description.GroupName}", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Example Service",
                    Description = "Example Service -- Backend Service Project",
                    Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                    
                });
                options.SwaggerDoc($"Payments{description.GroupName}", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Example Service",
                    Description = "Example Service -- Backend Service Project",
                    Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                });
                // Orders & Payments are the groupName above ex: out put will be : swagger/OrdersV1.0/swagger.json ( if you select Orders from the swagger definition dropdown) 
                // If you select Payments => output : swagger/PaymentsV1.0/swagger.json
            }
            
            
var app = builder.Build();
                
            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(
            swaggerOptions =>
            {                   
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    swaggerOptions.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swagger/Orders{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",$"Orders  {description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()}" );
                    swaggerOptions.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swagger/Payments{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", $"Payments  {description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()}");
                }
            });
```

**Controller
//V1
// example controller 1:**

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Orders")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
```

**// example controller 2:**

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Payments")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class PaymentsController : ControllerBase
```