# Failed to load API definition. Swagger 500 error

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

After adding the following controller to the running Swagger, a 500 error started to appear.

I created MyController in the same way as the other controllers, but I think I missed something, I cannot solve the error.

MyController.cs

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase{

        [HttpGet("GetList")]
        public async Task<ResponseModel> GetList([FromBody] GetListRequestModel requestModel)
{...}
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
 {
     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
     {
         ...
     }
     );
 });

 app.UseSwagger().UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
 });
```

[image]

Comment: What's the version of asp.net core do you use ?

Comment: Besides, request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body, don't use `[FromBody]` with get . Do you have other Get method in the `MyController` ? "I created MyController in the same way as the other controllers,"  Before you create the   MyController ,is it work ?

Comment: I checked and saw that what you said was correct, but even though I removed frombody, the error was still not resolved.

Comment: This error is not caused by  `[FromBody]` , it is just a reminder not to use it this way. From your code above , I test it without this error.
 Coud you share your full code of  startup and MyController  ? If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.

Comment: It seems that you can pinpoint the error by clicking on swagger link in console, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788911/500-error-when-setting-up-swagger-in-asp-net-core-mvc-6-app